# Hide elements in the view if the model state is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, design-patterns

Imagine a simple form that takes an email input like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "email", FormMethod.Post, new {  @id = "my__form" }))
{
    <div class="field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @placeholder = "Enter your email", @type = "email" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Save email</button>
    <div class='spinner'></div>
}
```

The `spinner` is not displayed initially (CSS):

```
   .spinner {
       display: none;
   }
```

On form submit I show a spinner on the page:

```
$('.btn').on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#my__form').submit();
   $('.spinner').show();
});
```

My action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("email")]
public ActionResult Save(EmailViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do stuff with email 
        return RedirectToAction("action", "contoller");
    }
    return View(model);
 }
```

Think of the above as pseudo-code that represents a more generic issue.

If a model state is invalid and the UI is updated in some way (in this case showing a spinner), what's the pattern or mechanism to reset the form?

For clarity, I am not talking here about standard data validation etc. I've tried having a hidden input on the form that I can populate using `ModelState.AddModelError("spinner", false)` and then acts as a 'switch' that javascript can read and then hide the spinner. This feels like a hack.

It feels like this is a common problem to which there is a common solution?

Comment: Its not clear what your are doing. You cancel the submit in the script but then call `.submit()` anyway so you have left the page (your `$('.spinner').show();` makes no sense). And why are you wanting to reset the form?

Comment: My example is somewhat contrived. Suppose I can only check the validity of an input server side. Also suppose I want to show the spinner on submit. If I find the input is invalid, how do I return the view to show a validation error and also remove the spinner from displaying?

Comment: You can always make an ajax call to check you validity, or use a `[Remote]` attribute (and if validity is dependent on other properties in the model  - as opposed to an external resource such as a database - you can write a custom `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` so that you get client and server side validation)

Comment: If using an ajax call, show the spinner at the beginning. In the method, return a 'error message' if invalid, and display it in the success callback (and hide the spinner)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The hack you mentioned is really how it would be done using normal ASP.NET MVC.

There can be different implementations, such as storing the flag in a `ViewBag` instead. But the idea is the same.

You might be better off posting the form via AJAX, whose result might include a success flag and/or a list of validation errors. You can then manipulate the DOM in the submit handler via JavaScript based on this result.